# How to find the first positive element position per row given a 2D numpy array without using loop

Tags: python, numpy

All. Given a 2D numpy array, How to find out the row and column index of the first positive element per row  without using loop. For example, given data

```
data = np.array([[1.0, -2.0, 3.0,3],
                 [0.0, 1.5, -2.0,5],
                 [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0,-5]])
```

How to find the indices of each positive element per row. It is expecting to get 2 1d indices as an answer, `row_idx=[0,1]`, `col_idx=[0,1]` which corresponds to elements `[1,1.5]` from data.
Anyone can shed a light on this, many thanks in advance!!!

I have tried using

```
import numpy as np
print(data)
row_idx = np.any(data>0, axis=1)
col_idx = np.argmax(data>0,axis=1)
print('row indices: ', row_idx)
print('col indices: ', col_idx)
print(data[row_idx,col_idx])
```

But could not get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you need to filter out the result of [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to remove the cases in which no value was greater than 0:

```
m1 = data>0
m2 = m1.any(axis=1)

row_idx = np.arange(data.shape[0])[m2]
col_idx = np.argmax(m1, axis=1)[m2]

print('row indices: ', row_idx)
print('col indices: ', col_idx)
print(data[row_idx,col_idx])
```

Output:

```
row indices:  [0 1]
col indices:  [0 1]
[1.  1.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.any` returns a `boolean` mask, not the indices. You can use `np.where` to get the indices directly.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1.0, -2.0, 3.0, 3],
                 [0.0, 1.5, -2.0, 5],
                 [-1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -5]])

col_idx = np.argmax(data > 0, axis=1)

rows_with_positive = np.any(data > 0, axis=1)

row_idx = np.where(rows_with_positive)[0]

col_idx = col_idx[rows_with_positive]

print('row indices: ', row_idx)
print('col indices: ', col_idx)
print(data[row_idx, col_idx])
```

Comment: Yes, `col_idx = col_idx[rows_with_positive]` was the answer I could not get my head around. Thanks.